# How to use virtualFields in a model with different aliases?

Tags: php, cakephp

well the main problems involves two Models, USER and MESSAGE, they have a relationship because what message does is the following:

Messages can be sent by the Users to other users.. so i have to identify who is the sender and who is te receiver, and im doing it by setting two Model Aliases to USER, which are 'Sender' and 'Receiver' (like this).

```
//This is on User model
'MessageSender' => array(
        'className' => 'Message',
        'foreignKey' => 'sender_id'
    ),
    'MessageRecipient' => array(
        'className' => 'Message',
        'foreignKey' => 'recipient_id'
    ),
```

and the relationship in Messages is something like this.

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Recipient' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'recipient_id'
    ),
    'Sender' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'sender_id'
    )
);
```

Up to here everything is fine..

Whenever i have to create a message i have a dropdown that shows me the complete list of the user first_names, but because i need to know everyone's last_name i've created a $virtualField to join them (first_name and last_name) like this.

```
//this is located on the USER model
public $virtualFields = array(
    'fullname' =>   'CONCAT(Recipient.first_name, " ", Recipient.last_name)'
);
```

How i am using the Users in the message creation? well i'm using the person who is going to send a new message as the Sender, so the Sender is the user's id and the Receiver is the selected user in the drop down...

[image: Selecting the Receiver]

the main problem is when i try to access any other part of the website that references the USER model, it throws me this error:

```
Database Error
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Recipient.first_name' in 'field list'
```

and of course is because my virtualField is expecting a result from the 'Recipient.first_name' and 'Recipient.last_name' to join them together, but because i'm not using Recivers and Senders all the time... (because those are just for the Message model usage) it throws me an error
How should i handle this? is there any way i can put any conditional (if else) so the User model will not to use

```
User.first_name
```

and instead use

```
Receive.first_name
```

or vice versa?

if you need any other information please ask, i'll be very thankful, Best Regards!

Comment: Do you need this virtual field only once or you use it in many places of your project?

Comment: Yes, i need it only on this part of the project..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you can do this two ways. First, you can define this virtual field on the fly, before your `find()`:

```
$this->YourModel->virtualFields = array('fullname' => 'CONCAT(Recipient.first_name, " ", Recipient.last_name)');
$this->YourModel->find(...);
```

or (if you have more virtual fields)

```
$this->YourModel->virtualFields['fullname'] = 'CONCAT(Recipient.first_name, " ", Recipient.last_name)';
$this->YourModel->find(...);
```

The second way, which is more flexible for future, you can append this virtual field in `beforeFind()` callback basing on some switch variable. So before your find query you can activate a switch and this virtual field will be appended to query.

```
class YourModel extends AppModel {
    private $_fullNameEnabled = false;

    public function beforeFind($queryData) {
        parent::beforeFind($queryData);

        if (!empty($this->_fullNameEnabled)) {
            $this->virtualFields = array('fullname' => 'CONCAT(Recipient.first_name, " ", Recipient.last_name)');
        }

        return $queryData;
    }

    public function fullnameFieldStatus($status = true) {
        $this->_fullNameEnabled = $status;
    }
}
```

And then before you call `find()` use:

```
$this->YourModel->fullnameFieldStatus();
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a 3rd way also: dynamically construct the virtual field, taking into consideration the alias that your model is being referenced as.

```
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
    $this->virtualFields['fullname'] = sprintf("CONCAT(%s.first_name, ' ', %s.last_name)", 
            , $this->alias, $this->alias);
}
```

With this technique, you can use:

- User.fullname
- Sender.fullname
- Recipient.fullname